# How does graphics set look if made for 2D games?

Tags: android, ios, 2d-games

We created graphics for many mobile apps, but this is the first time our designer has to create graphics for 2D game.

Should he create a Photoshop file like in mobile app projects or there are some specific things when creating 2D-game graphics?

I tried to find answer on the net, but I found nothing on this specific issue. I would appreciate someone who is familiar with game coding replies as he had probably received graphics to implement into his code.

Comment: This question would probably be more relevant on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically most 2D games are tile based.

So your designers should provide graphics files where all possible artifacts and animations are visible.

Afterwards you need to take snippets from those images to create tile sets that are usable by the game engine that you are using for each game level.

An example of editors for tile set editing is the famous Tiled, http://www.mapeditor.org/.

The game engine is then takes care of for locating a tile set for the given level, and using the available tiles for the background and character animations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it depends on what tools/frameworkds you want to use...

If you intend to use cocos2d (really nice 2D mobile game framework), then you should definitely have a look at CocosBuilder (http://cocosbuilder.com), a great editor for collaboration between designer and developer.